# Move BC before/after reformatting

Tags: backup, installation

I plan on reformatting my main drive. I did this once before and of course lost access to my Bitcoin Core wallet and the Bitcoins therein.

Does anybody know how I can go about transferring my Bitcoins before or after I reformat my drive?

Can I just copy and paste the Bitcoin Core folder to my second drive before formatting, and then transfer it back afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just copy your `wallet.dat` from your local wallet directory. If using windows it will be in `%appdata%/Bitcoin`. After reformatting download a fresh copy of Bitcoin Core and replace the wallet.dat with the one you saved prior to reformatting.

There's also the method of using the `backupwallet` and `importwallet` commands. https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#backupwallet